# Nativescript iOS Action Bar Subtitle

Tags: ios, nativescript

I'm attempting to put a subtitle under a title in the action bar on iOS. While there is [this solution](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/subtitle-for-action-bar/4785) for Android it doesn't work on iOS at all. Is there any way to do this on iOS?

```
<ActionBar [title]="This works" [subTitle]="I want a subtitle here"></ActionBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS doesn't have a subtitle option. But you could use a [custom title view](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/action-bar#using-a-custom-title-view) and wrap two labels one below another.

Answer (score 0):

iOS has some sort of subtitle, but it is named as `prompt` (for more detail, you can see the doc for [UINavigationBar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar?language=objc)).

Unfortunately, you can't set its value from XML, so you need to use some handler - I create [simple playground to demonstrate `prompt` property](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=nECEQj&v=3).