# how to add subtitle in action bar in ios/andriod using nativescript with angular?

Tags: angular, nativescript

[image]I need to add a subtitle in navigation bar. Already i have a back button, title and edit icon and below these need to add subtitle text using nativescript with angular for ios and andriod

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nativescript iOS Action Bar Subtitle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244115/nativescript-ios-action-bar-subtitle)

Comment: above link not working and the controls are aligned properly. its always place in center

Comment: Please provide sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a playground [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=44Nr26).

```
<ActionBar >
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical" ios:horizontalAlignment="left" backgroundColor="green" width="100%"
        android:horizontalAlignment="left">
        <Label text="Title" width="100%" backgroundColor="red" textAlignment="center"></Label>
        <Label text="Subtitle"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ActionBar>
```

Comment: Code which is working perfectly.. Is it possible to increase the action bar height in IOS?